# Symfony security basic authentication

Tags: php, symfony

From the symfony book http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#security-authorization I'm trying to set up the basic http authentication.

The `security.yml` file looks like this:

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        default:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~

        access_control:
            - { path: ^/login, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

But as soon as I add

```
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I get a symfony error saying:

```
InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 309:
Unrecognized option "0" under "security.firewalls.access_control"
```

What am I doing wrong? What to do to fix it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your indentation isn't good

`access_control` key can't stay under `firewalls` node

You should modify your security.yml as follows

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt|error)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        default:
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic: ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: oooh thank you @DonCallisto! Now I know that whitespace also really matters a lot in `.yml` files! Will accepct as soon as I can

Comment: @caramba: Of course they matter, otherwise file can't be parsed

Answer (score 2):

Remember that if you require `ROLE_USER` to your `/login` path then an unauthorised user can't login to your app.